# Migration from was 9 to liberty 19.0.0.9, problem with resources.xml and jndi

Tags: configuration, websphere, websphere-liberty

I have a problem with migration from was 9 to liberty 19.

Plenty of configurations in was 9 is placed in resources.xml file .I do not know how to migrate it to liberty server. 
Second problem is that i used migration tool from eclipse and it created server.xml file with for example datasource configuration but all of them are not available in jndi (@Resource or InitialContext.lookup).

Could somebody provide some examples how to configure this part of server?

Best regards
Rafal

Comment: There are examples for data source configuration here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_dep_configuring_ds.html.  If you update the question with your server.xml we can provide more feedback on changes that need to be made.

Comment: Thank You for answer. I have lerned alot during This time and i managed with it but i stll have some problems. I have two ear on container and i have problem with call ejb object from another ear. I get class cast exception. I am trying to create global class loader but i have read that there is no functionality to dil with it on liberty profile.

Comment: I can not lookup remote interface. I get error that liberty has no feature to run remote interface but in features i have installed remote Ejb. I am run out of idea.

Comment: Can you update the question with your server.xml? There are example uses of remote EJBs in the Open Liberty tests: here's a [server.xml](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/blob/integration/dev/com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.remote_fat/publish/servers/com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.remote.fat.RemoteServer/server.xml) and here's a [lookup](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/blob/integration/dev/com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.remote_fat/test-applications/CrossAppRemoteClient.war/src/com/ibm/ws/ejbcontainer/remote/fat/crossapp/client/CrossAppTestServlet.java).

Comment: Thank You for all comments .During the weekend i have found the solution. I had bed keystore for liberty. I regenerated new credentials, new  key.p12 was generated. After that corba has started and now i can call remote interface. Thank you very much.